# change nav bar to link other fragment

Tags: android, kotlin, navigation

[image: my nav bar]

I need some idea to how to change nav bar link to other fragment

For example, there are 3 nav bar button, name it A=mainfragment, B=joingroupfragment or groupfragment, C=profilefragment

user have to login
if user doesnt have group, in B will have joingroupfragment, else will have groupfragment

i have try to do "if else" inside joingroupfragment to redirect user that have group to groupfragment, but groupfragment also appear in A and C nav bar